# Magento 1 Display Category Title on cms Home page

Tags: magento, content-management-system

how can I display Category title on this way:

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="featured1" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" after="cms_page">

<action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>3</category_id></action>

<!-- WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE? -->

</block>

</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the Category name from admin panel.

OR you have to check the source file where categories been assigned.

And change the datatype and format in source file.